# Angular Material/Jasmine testing - errors while loading Material Harnesses

Tags: angular, testing, async-await, angular-material, jasmine

I'm trying to test components built with Angular Material, however I'm encountering a problem initializing Material elements using `Harness Loader` [as per documentation (section 'Getting started'.)](https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses). I'd like to extract the logic of initializing them outside of the test methods to make them more concise, but it doesn't seem to work.

Within `describe()`:

```js
let usernameFormField: MatFormFieldHarness;
let registrationButton: MatButtonHarness;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [RegistrationComponent],
        providers: [ /*provide spies */ ]
    }).compileComponents().then(async () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegistrationComponent);
        loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);

        // what works, but I don't like
        /*loader.getHarness(
            MatFormFieldHarness.with({selector: '#username-form-field'})
        ).then(harness => {
            usernameFormField = harness;
        });*/

        // what doesn't work
        usernameFormField = await loader
            .getHarness(MatFormFieldHarness.with({selector: '#username-form-field'}))

        // other form elements

        // to my confusion, this works without any problem
        registrationButton = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness);
    });
}));
```

The `await` on `loader.getHarness()` causes lots of errors, seemingly about code not running in 'ProxyZone'.

```
context.js:265 Unhandled Promise rejection: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.
    at Function.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent (zone-testing.js:210) [<root>]
    at Function.setup (testbed.js:61) [<root>]
    at new TestbedHarnessEnvironment (testbed.js:572) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.createEnvironment (testbed.js:633) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.createComponentHarness (testing.js:341) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.<anonymous> (testing.js:384) [<root>]
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:74:1 [<root>]
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:960) [<root>]
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:70) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment._getQueryResultForElement (testing.js:379) [<root>]
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing.js:366:1 [<root>]
    at Array.map (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.<anonymous> (testing.js:366) [<root>] Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.
    at Function.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:210:1) [<root>]
    at Function.setup (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing/testbed.js:61:1) [<root>]
    at new TestbedHarnessEnvironment (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing/testbed.js:572:1) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.createEnvironment (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing/testbed.js:633:1) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.createComponentHarness (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing.js:341:1) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing.js:384:1) [<root>]
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:74:1 [<root>]
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:960:1) [<root>]
    at __awaiter (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:70:1) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment._getQueryResultForElement (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing.js:379:25) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing.js:366:1 [<root>]
    at Array.map (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at TestbedHarnessEnvironment.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing.js:366:1) [<root>]
```

I'd also tried running this with a global `async` function (with the following syntax:)

```js
beforeEach(async( async () => {
    // magic happening here
}));
```

I even tried extracting these harnesses into separate functions, to call them as late as possible, but it also didn't work well:

```js
const usernameFormField = () => {
    loader.getHarnes(...);
}

// later in code; not the most elegant, but good enough
const usernameField = await usernameFormField();
expect(await usernameField().hasErrors()).toBeFalsy();
```

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963635/angular-7-testing-async-function-call-async-await) discusses, the 'double-async' construct is valid, if a little clumsy. However, it didn't work for me; the only variant that did was `beforeEach(async( () => { ... } ));`. Is it possible to use async-await inside `beforeEach` in async zone, or am I stuck with handling everything manually using Promises?

**EDIT**: a similar problem shows up not only in `beforeEach()`, but also in test methods themselves, even when I don't preinitialize the harnesses:

```js
it('should display \'log out\' and \'my account\' buttons when user is authenticated',
    async () => {
        const EXAMPLE_USERNAME = 'username';

        spyOnProperty(authenticationService, 'authenticatedUser')
            .and.returnValue(EXAMPLE_USERNAME);

       expect(fixture.componentInstance.authenticatedUser)
.toEqual(EXAMPLE_USERNAME);

        const logOutButton = await loader
            .getHarness(MatButtonHarness.with({text: BUTTON_LOG_OUT_TEXT}));
        expect(await logOutButton.isDisabled()).toBeFalsy();

        // the following line causes a problem
        /*const myAccountButton = await loader
            .getHarness(MatButtonHarness.with({text: BUTTON_MY_ACCOUNT_TEXT}));
        expect(await myAccountButton.isDisabled()).toBeFalsy();
        await myAccountButton.click();
        expect(routerSpy.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();*/
    });
```

When I uncomment only the first commented line, the code breaks and the test doesn't pass. **When I include the async zone, the test passes, but the errors persist.** I initially thought this is a problem with initializing the component, but now it seems it's more related to HarnessLoader.

**EDIT 2**: Coderer's answer links to some problems with `karma.conf.js`, so here are some of my configuration files:

`karma.conf.js`:

```js
// custom headless chrome from
// https://coryrylan.com/blog/building-angular-cli-projects-with-github-actions

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // adding any files here didn't seem to work
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/elx-front-end'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
      }
    }
  });
};
```

`src/test.ts`: (importing as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11317#issuecomment-245215143) also didn't work)

```ts
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import "zone.js/dist/zone-testing";
import {getTestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context("./", true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

`tsconfig.base.json`:

```json
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "es2020",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2018",
        "strict": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "paths": { /* custom paths */}
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.spec.json`:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
        "types": [
            "jasmine",
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

fragment of `angular.json`:

```json
"architect": {
    ...
    "test": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
        "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
                "src/styles.scss",
                "src/dimens.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?  I noticed that the "expected to be in ProxyZone" errors go away if I don't include `zone-patch-rxjs-fake-async`, but calls to `loader.getAllHarnesses` never resolve.

Comment: See my answer below about including `zone-patch-etc` in the right order, but also, my calls to `loader.getAllHarnesses` *actually* fail to resolve because they call `fixture.whenStable()` under the hood, and `whenStable` never resolves if the component under test uses `setInterval` at all.  I'm still poking at that one.

Comment: Hey, I've noticed your answer only now. I'll take a look in a moment and let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I filed issue [21632](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/21632) about this for Angular 11, because the setup is as it is described in the documentation's [Getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses). The primary culprit is the `beforeEach` function, and there are three potential solutions.

#### Option 1

The `async` function has been [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/async) and was replaced with `waitForAsync`. Using `waitForAsync` in the `beforeEach` instead of an asynchronous function is one way to resolve the issue as of Angular 11 ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/harness-issue-o9ehmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-harness-example.spec.ts)).

```js
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [RegistrationComponent]
  }).compileComponents().then(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegistrationComponent);
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    usernameFormField = await loader
      .getHarness(MatFormFieldHarness.with({selector: '#username-form-field'}))
    registrationButton = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness);
  });
}));
```

#### Option 2

Passing an async function to the `beforeEach` without `waitForAsync`, also works for your specific case ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/harness-issue-jzhgwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-harness-example.spec.ts)). However, when not handling the `compileComponents` promise, as most documentation does, move the call to `TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader` to the `it` function ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/harness-issue-zy6k6c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-harness-example.spec.ts)).

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [MatButtonModule],
    declarations: [ButtonHarnessExample]
  }).compileComponents();
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ButtonHarnessExample);
});

it('should click a button', async () => {
  const loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  const button = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness.with({text: 'Basic button'}));
});
```

#### Option 3

Change the target to ES2016 in tsconfig.json ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/harness-issue-anrpvn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-harness-example.spec.ts)).

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es2016"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! It was enough to downgrade the target; apparently, I didn't come to think that it might be the cause, even though the CLI warns about potential issues with `async/await` in newer targets.

Comment: changing the target from es2017 to es2016 worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing errors about `ProxyZone`, you probably have your Zone dependencies loading in the wrong order.  There is some detail in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11317) but honestly they just did a pretty bad job of documenting how to set up your own tests with Zone.  (The current [testing intro page](https://angular.io/guide/testing) says "The CLI takes care of Jasmine and Karma configuration for you.", which must be nice... if you created your project with the CLI.)

I had the same error you're getting, and got past it by putting this in my `karma.conf.ts`:

```
        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            // Everybody needs Zone, probably
            "node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js",
            "node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-patch-rxjs-fake-async.umd.js",
            "node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js",
            { pattern: "./src/app/**/*.spec.ts", type: "js" }
        ],
```

I *think* your error comes if you either don't include `patch-rxjs-fake-async`, or if you import it after `zone-testing`, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, importing these files either in `karma.conf.js` or `test.ts` didn't help (then, actually none of the tests passed). I updated the question with some (possibly) relevant configuration files; I'd appreciate it if you took a look at them.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that including `zone-patch-rxjs-fake-async` causes all your tests to fail?  What error message do you get?  I'm not sure how much I can help, other than to say that I got the "expected to be in ProxyZone" error without it and now I don't.